# Need Applescript to repeat every x number of seconds

Tags: osx-lion, applescript

Here is my script so far:

```
property timeDelay : 5

on appOpen(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to set appNameIsRunning to exists (processes where name is appName)
    return appNameIsRunning
end appOpen

if appOpen("iChat") then
    tell application "iChat"
        repeat with theService in services
            if connection status of theService = disconnected or connection status of theService = disconnecting then
                log in of service (name of theService)
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end if
```

Basically, it checks a single time if any of your iChat/Messages accts are logged out. If they are, log them in. It works.

However, I would like this to be a 'Stay Open' app. In the past I've used the pattern

```
on idle
    -- do stuff
end idle
```

..but for some reason it's erroring when I try to compile.

[image: the error I'm getting]
Any idea why this would be happening?

EDIT:

Ok -- still not sure why this was occurring, but I was able to fix the problem by simply making a new script. I have no idea why this error was coming up but it looks like it's good now. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You should replace your delay with a return.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense...

```
tell application "System Events" to set appNameIsRunning to exists (processes where name is appName)
```

You want this...

```
tell application "System Events" to set appNameIsRunning to exists process appName
```

The reason is that "processes where name is appName" will return a list (whether it has one item or many it's still a list) and it makes no sense to check "exists" of a list.

I'm not sure about the error but I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't solve my problem but your change was noted and I updated my script.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on 10.6.8

```
property timeDelay : 5

on appOpen(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to set appNameIsRunning to exists process appName
    return appNameIsRunning
end appOpen

on idle
    if appOpen("iChat") then
        tell application "iChat"
            repeat with theService in services
                if connection status of theService = disconnected or connection status of theService = disconnecting then
                    tell service (name of theService) to log in
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end if
    return timeDelay
end idle
```